# Notifcation status icons become white when i genreate notification in andorid 5.0

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am getting my notification icons become white when i am using below code in android 5(L)

here is my code :

```
private void generateSimpleNotification(){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        mNotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mNotificationBuilder.setContentText("App notification text here");

        mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("App notification Title here");

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app

        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this,NotificationActivity.class);

         // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.

        TaskStackBuilder mStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)

        mStackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationParentActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        mStackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


        PendingIntent mPendingIntent=mStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

i am using below icons for  `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Below are icons size

drawable-hdpi 72x72

drawable-mdpi 48x48

drawable-xhdpi 96x96

drawable-xhdpi 144x144

Now problem is my android luncher icons become white in status bar of my notification and how to resolved it.

below is screen shot [image: notification with white icons]

Comment: I think you cant affect that? Notifications from lollipop have changed a lot and its always color white/gray + transparency.. Better to wait someone to confirm, but AFAIK in android 5.0+ it's like this in status bar..

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic YES you are right but still i will look forward if any one can able to use color full notification icon .

Comment: I doubt that you can make change to that.. In status bar I think its always gonna be white + transparent and in 'action' you can set whatever you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching little bit , it's look like from andorid 5.0 we can use only white on transparent background image only i have read it below developer site

[Android notification guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

from above site they have said below

```
Notification icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image.
```